# how to get filename from a handle

Tags: process, filenames

I want to know what file process 1234 is writing to.

```
$ strace -etrace=write -p 1234
```

shows handles, how do I get file name from the handle?

Comment: Might get an answer on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know what file process 1234 is writing to.

You can try `lsof -p`

```
cnicutar@lemon:~$ lsof -p $$
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
bash    22364 cnicutar  cwd    DIR    8,6     4096  262145 /home/cnicutar
bash    22364 cnicutar  rtd    DIR    8,5     4096       2 /
bash    22364 cnicutar  txt    REG    8,5   955024 2616381 /bin/bash
....
bash    22364 cnicutar    0u   CHR  136,0      0t0       3 /dev/pts/0
bash    22364 cnicutar    1u   CHR  136,0      0t0       3 /dev/pts/0
bash    22364 cnicutar    2u   CHR  136,0      0t0       3 /dev/pts/0
```

Alternatively you could go in `/proc/PID/fd` and look at the descriptor (using maybe `readlink`).

Comment: I'm searching for which config file the app writes to, when a change is made it opens, writes, closes: so my strace options are wrong. I think I need "strace -p1234 -etrace=open,write" then parse the result. (is there a way to put a linefeed in this comment? ... <enter> submits it ...)